# How to apply page template in divi theme of wordpress instead of using page builder?

Tags: wordpress

Hello need to use traditional page template instead of using provided page builder as client want some business logic to hide for users.
After installing theme, it wan't allow me to use page selection.

Answer (score 0):

in your theme directory, open et-pagebuilder folder the open et-pagebuilder.php file in your editor. locate the code below (around line 77 - 78) and remove or disable it (by adding double slash before to make it a comment) so you can enable it in the future.

```
if ( 'page' === $post->post_type )
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'default' );
```

Comment: commenting that out doesn't give the desired results. It delivers a blank page. I assume the Divi theme requires a page to use the default template page or it throws an error.